# How to return the array repeated three time in a single array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty sure I've done most of the code correctly but I'm returning the wrong thing? I've tried using copyOf() but still had the same issue. It looks like I'm returning the object of an array rather than the elements? I need the method treble to return the original array repeated in order, three times in one array. So [1,2,3,] should look like [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3] when trebled. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArrayExercises
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int SIZE = 5;
        int[] array = new int[SIZE];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter whole number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            int input = scanner.nextInt(); // get input from the user
            array[i] = input; // store the value in the array
        }    
        printArray("Input array:", array);
        // call method sum and print out the result
        int sum = sum(array);
        System.out.println("The sum of elements is " + sum);
        // call method repeat and print out the result
        int[] trebled = repeat(array);
        System.out.println("The repeated array is " + trebled);
    }    
    public static void printArray(String msg, int[] array)
    {
        System.out.println(msg + " " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }
    public static int sum(int[] array) 
    {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            s += array[i];
        return s;    
    }    
    public static int[] repeat(int[] array) //this is the part I'm having trouble with
    {
        int len = array.length;
        int[] multiplied = new int[len*3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                multiplied[i * len + j] = array[j];
            }
        }
return multiplied;}
}
```

Comment: You have a method printArray(), why you only use it to print the Input array but not the repeated one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
System.out.println("The repeated array is "  + Arrays.toString(trebled));
```

to print your array instead of printing using the array variable name, because otherwise that will print the address of the array rather than the content.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

your method is ok, the issue is how you print it because as mentioned in the comments you do not use your printArray() method in this case.

So try changing this line :

```
System.out.println("The repeated array is " + trebled);
```

to :

```
printArray("The repeated array is " , trebled);
```